# Migrating wordpress from domain to another - But URL still redirects to old domain

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect, phpmyadmin, migration

I have moved one of my website to a new domain, after i have uploaded everything in place homepage is working fine. But all the links and images are still coming from old domain. below is what i did.

- Backed up database
- Uploaded all the files to the new server.
- Imported sql into new server via `phpmyadmin`
- Now i have used [this](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) script to change URL in database.

Now, problems i am facing are:

- All the links are going to `old domain.`
- All the images are linked to `old domain.`
- wp-admin is also redirected to `old domain` when i try to run `mydomain.com/wp-admin`

Please help if you have any ideas about this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: once you finish search and replace DB check wp_option and wp_post table in database whether URL have been change to new domain or not...

Comment: There is a link called `View Changes` i have checked that the URLs are changed successfully. From Old domain to New domain.

Answer (score 1):

Did you change your urls in `wp-config.php`?

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

**Edit:**

Use phpMyAdmin and verify the fields `siteurl` and `home` in your `wp_options` table. These two fields should contain your correct domain.

Comment: No i didn't added `define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');` but i have changed database, prefix, and host info.

Comment: you should change these constants to your new domain...
You dont have to add them, they're already there but should be changed

Comment: That code was not there in wp-config.php file, I have tried adding them but after that everything is disturbed the design is not coming okay not. And wp-admin returns `No Found.`

Comment: please check your siteurl and home fields in the wp_options table, i've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

My issue is resolved, i am posting this as an answer so that someone else can benefit out of it.

My issue was, `siteurl` and `homeurl` were not updated, so i have placed `define('RELOCATE',true);` in my `wp-config.php` file. And again tried to access the website , it gone to the correct url but all the `css` was gone. Then i headed over to `wp-admin` and it also came with no `css` but still i tried to login but this time it has taken me to the correct `url` and `with css` login page but didn't logged in. Then Again i have attempted to login and this time i have logged in successfully. Then i have changed both the `urls` from `settings` in the admin panel.

Hope this helps someone else dealing with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, You should use duplicator plugin for this task, It will make our work so easy and handle all the issues itself.
I also have this issue now I have made this through duplicator plugin of WordPress it works for me perfectly.